# passing data from contentscripts.js to popup.js via storage local

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm still busy with my first extension. I just want to pass over some data (an array) from contentscripts.js to popup.js. As I read it in several sources the easiest way would be using local storage.

This is what I tried:

*contentscripts.js* (I don't really know if that one works)

```
...
alert(isotopeIndices[0]);  // Array isotopeIndices has lots entries
chrome.storage.local.set(isotopeIndices[0]);  //goal would be to save the whole array: chrome.storage.local.set(isotopeIndices);
```

*popup.js*

```
chrome.storage.local.get(
    function(isotopeIndices) {
        document.getElementById('selectIsotopes').innerHTML = isotopeIndices[0];
    }
);
```

My popup shows in the `<div id="selectIsotopes">...</div>`-Element only undefined. This is why I think that the `chrome.storage.local.set` doesn't work at all.
Concerning the Google-HowTo (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) everything should be correct.

Even though the question is, is local storage the simplest way to pass the data...?

Thanks for your time and help!!!

Comment: `chrome.storage` is a key-value system. You need to have an object with a key that identifies what you're storing and trying to retrieve: `set({ "myIsotopes" : isotopeIndices })` with `get("myIsotopes", function() { ... })`

Comment: Content scripts can't use most chrome api's ([source](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)).  I think you want [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html).

Comment: Ok, I got it with the key-value system. But with message passing I could only communicate with the background.js, because the popup is not open all the time, isn't it? So a listener would not make sense!

Comment: @apsillers: Ok, I changed my code to what you wrote but `get` still has no value and I got the message _undefined_

Comment: Use `chrome.storage.local.get('myIsotopes', function(items) {... = items['myIsotopes']}`